# Selenium/Python Jquery popup

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, selenium

I am trying to click "OK" on my localhost for a popup window that is generated with Jquery. I tried switching to the window that didn't work

```
handleName = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(handleName)
```

then I also tried doing a javascript popup but its a Jquery so it wouldn't work

```
alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
browser.close()
```

what are my other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

driver.window_handles returns a list of all opened windows. Just tried switch_to.window() and it raised error because it needs only one name and not a list.

1. If jquery generates actual browser window you can switch to the popup window by its name/title if it has one:

   driver.switch_to.window("Alert popup!")

In the situation when the current and popup windows have equal titles I use something like this:

```
current_window = driver.current_window_handle
_handles = driver.window_handles
<popup opening button>.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
    expected_conditions.new_window_is_opened(_handles))
try:
    #find new window handle
    popup_window = (h for h in
            driver.window_handles if h != current_window).next()
except StopIteration:
    raise Exception("No popup!")
```

2. If jquery generates some popup-styled <div> (not browser window), so you just locate it like any other element on the page with driver.find_element_by_<...>